# Careers question button I'm Not Interested click results in duplicated message

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The text after "Got it!" is duplicated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops. Yeah, that's not supposed to happen. Pushing a fix for it right now. Thanks for the tip!